# Where is /proc/scsi/scsi in Debian 6?

Tags: debian, scsi, linux

I recently installed Debian 6 in a VM on ESXi 4.1, but I noticed there is no `/proc/scsi/scsi`.  Am I missing a module which provides that, or is there a different way of doing things like `echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 1 0">/proc/scsi/scsi`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On recent kernels the `/proc/scsi` is being "migrated" to sysfs. You can recompile the kernel and enable the `CONFIG_SCSI_PROC_FS: legacy /proc/scsi/ support` to the scsi subsystem, or see if something under `/sys/class/scsi_host` and other sysfs dirs have what you need. 
The legacy support is a good route if you have many tools that rely on /proc/scsi to work.

Answer (score 2):

The new way of adding scsi devices is.

```
echo "$c $t $l" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host$h/scan
```

$h is the HBA number, $c is the channel on the HBA, $t is the SCSI target ID, and $l is the LUN.

If you don't know all of that, you can use wildcards.

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host$h/scan
```

This is documented in the [online storage management](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch21.html) section of Red Hat's [storage administration guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/index.html).